# Exclude entities currently referenced on a node with entity browser

Tags: entities

I have content type that references a custom entity and uses an entity browser widget to select them.

I want to create a view for the entity browser that excludes entities that have already been selected on the current node so that they're not selected twice.

Not sure if this can be done with default functionality or it needs a custom module

Comment: Are you asking about entities that have already been saved, or merely selected and not yet saved? You'd need javascript for the latter.

Comment: My question was regarding the first scenario, the second scenario sounds useful but I'll move it into a different question if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You are listing entities as your base type, but you want to filter based on the current node.

You need to introduce the information about the nodes that already reference (all) entities, and also what the current node is.

You do that by using the "backwards" Relationship, the one that goes from Entities back to the nodes that reference them. This Relatinship will be named something like `Content using field_entity_reference` and its Description will be `Relate each Content with a field_entity_reference set to the content.`

It will *not* be named "Content referenced from field_entity_reference", that one is the "forward" Relationship.

You can **Require** this Relationship because you want the results that *do* have a reference from a node.

Then add the Contextual filter `Content: ID`, make it **use the Relationship**, and configure
`When the filter value is NOT available`
**Provide default value**
**Content ID from URL**
`When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
**Specify validation criteria**
**Content**
**Your CT**

Configure the other options as needed, but in the end:

`More`
**Exclude**

So we found all nodes that reference entities in our results, and used the Contextual filter to exclude the results related to the current node.